# How to get value from several inputs using knockout js?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have four inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
```

I need to retrieve data from this inputs and put them into array. I've tried to do it like this:

```
`var data = [];

    var viewModel = {
        Id: ko.observable(),
        Ids: ko.observableArray(data),
        showReports: function () {
            var container = $('input[type=text]');
            container.each(function() {
                if (container.val().trim().length > 0) {
                    data.push({ Id: container.val() });
                }
            });
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`
```

When I fill in first input with data, the others are filled as well,but I need to put there other data. How can I cope with this? In the future I will have more than 4 inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
<!-- ko foreach: Ids -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Id" />
<!-- /ko -->

var data = [];

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.Id = ko.observable();
    this.Ids = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }, { Id: 3 }]);
    this.showReports = function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < self.Ids().length)
            data.push(self.Ids()[i];
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```